# Multiple or multi purpose drag and drop DropTargets in wxPython

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I've successfully in the past created apps that have a `wx.FileDropTarget` that accepts files through drag and drop, and custom drag and drop targets from `wx.PyDropTarget`.

I'm trying to create an app that has a single control (`wx.ListCtrl`) that accepts files to be dropped from the file system, and also allows a custom drag and drop so the user is able to reorder the list, after dropping files in.

There's examples of different uses of drag and drop [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/20/wxpython-introduction-to-drag-and-drop/), all the examples work well individually however I've been unsuccessful at trying to get any working together.

As far as I'm aware you can only set one drop target on a control, I've tried using multiple inheritance to make a class that inherits from both `wx.PyDropTarget` and `wx.FileDropTarget` but this doesn't seem to work (neither type of drop works).

Does any know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about dynamically changing the nature of the drop target on a click on the ListCtrl items?   If the user clicks on a ListCtrl item, then they are about to commence drag and drop (so you need PyDropTarget, when they let go, then you're back to FileDropTarget.

I haven't tried this, just a suggestion.